# Optimal way to bind IEnumerable from Dapper query to ComboBox

Tags: c#, dapper

I am using Dapper as my ORM, and I have the following method for my User class:

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetList()
{
  using (SqlConnection sqlC = DAL.SQL.SFMConn())
  {
    string queryID = "select opID, RoleID, Password from [user]";
    return sqlC.Query<User>(queryID);
  }
}
```

I am then using a BindingSource to bind the result from above query, and using that BindingSource to fill a ComboBox:

```
Model.User user = new Model.User();
BindingSource users = new BindingSource();
users.DataSource = user.GetList();
```

My issue is I don't feel I'm doing this the optimal way. When I want to get my RoleID for the current user, I'm casting my current BindingSource record to Model.User:

```
int authLevel = ((Model.User)users.Current).RoleID;
```

Is there a better way to do this? A way to do this without using a BindingSource perhaps? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**combobox.selectedvalue=roleid**

combobox.displayvalue="some other field to enduser"

Comment: Thanks, but the ValueMember and DisplayMember needs to be the OpID. I need to access the RoleID in several other methods.

Answer (score 0):

In your case which `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` are reserved already, following event base call, may be the solution:

```
users.CurrentChanged += new System.EventHandler(UsersCurrentChanged);
void UsersCurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        authLevel = (users.Current as Model.User).RoleID;
    }
```